# java.lang.IllegalStateException: removeAttribute: Session already invalidated

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I am having a web application which is running on tomcat server. My application is fetching data from database. There are many additional calculations, so this may last about one hour or more. After this, when all operations are finished, I got this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: removeAttribute: Session already invalidated
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.removeAttribute(StandardSession.java:1262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.removeAttribute(StandardSession.java:1237)
>       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.removeAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:140)
>       at com.system.PageServlet.handleJsp(PageServlet.java:670)
>       at com.system.PageServlet.doRun(PageServlet.java:384)
>       at com.system.PageServlet.doGet(PageServlet.java:172)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at filters.ObjectsCacheFilter.doFilter(ObjectsCacheFilter.java:43)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at filters.FilterCach.doFilter(FilterCach.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**EDIT:** 
this is a code where I got the exception:

> session.removeAttribute("test1");
>   session.removeAttribute("test2");

Could someone help me?

Comment: Session timeout maybe? Try increasing it.

Comment: please include the code and what version is your tomcat

Comment: unless until you provide the complete code, can't tell exactly what caused the issue. It might be one the following reasons 1. you invalidate the session already or 2. session already expired